# Need tag for "civil rights"

Tags: discussion, tags

Unfortunately there seems to be no tag for civil rights.  Unfortunately I can't create one.

Comment: Why do you need to create the tag? Is there a question you wish for the tag to be added on? Are there related tags that can be used instead?

Comment: I would like to add a civil-rights tag to my question http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11891/foia-for-legal-fees; also, I think civil rights are an important topic, so there should be a tag about it.

Comment: Meh, that question really doesn't warrant it. If you find that a tag can be added, you could come to chat, we'll be able to add it for you :)

Answer (score 2):

There's already a "rights" tag.  The problem with a tag starting with "civil" is we have four other tags with the same first word.

In any case, this request should be joined to the existing unresolved question [What's the [rights] tag for?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/whats-the-rights-tag-for)

Comment: IMO, "civil rights" is a term of art that does *not* apply to FOIA. It's already annoying enough that we have a distinction between rights and human rights; trifurcating the concept of rights would be cause for head-shaking.

Comment: What I have seen is that if a parent files a human rights suit, that is very different from filing an Office for Civil Rights complaint.  (Btw there's an OCR for education, another for health care, another in Agriculture, not sure if there are more.)

Comment: FOIA is a tag.  Civil rights should be, in my opinion, a tag.  My Question happens to be related to both, but there could be plenty of other questions that might be related to only one or the other.

Comment: What is the difference between a right and a civil right? Are you specifically referring to "whatever is in the purview of the OCR of HHS"? That precludes housing, law enforcement, labor, education or employment discrimination.